# Pouchdb not syncing when there are attachments

Tags: pouchdb

My sync is failing when I initialise my local pouchdb with a remote couchdb having docs with attachments.

Below is the error:

```
pouchdb:api http://10.0.0.0:3000/db +14ms getAttachment error TypeError: response.buffer is not a function
    at index-browser.es.js:7100
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17289)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:889
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17280)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
browser.js:133 pouchdb:api http://10.0.0.0:3000/db +2s id
```

I'm using pouchdb-find to query documents.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your error does not appear to have anything to do with PouchDb.  PouchDb does not use `zone.js` as far as I can tell, but the error arises from that product.  You need to show the code that invokes the synchronization before anyone can help you with this.  Btw, I edited you question to make it easier to read.  Well formatted questions get help much more often than messy ones.

Comment: Also:  Zones is a quite recent and very advanced toolkit.  I doubt PouchDB has been tested for compatibility with it.  You should avoid Zones unless you can explain exactly why you need it.

Comment: What surprises me is that the log come from pouchdb:api. I've removed the use of zone and I'm still having he issue

Comment: I've removed the use of zone and I'm still having he issue. It really seems to appear in the sync method, I'm not doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

After investigation, I've made the sync working by modifying index-browser.es.js of index-browser.es.js file from pouchdb library.
I've  made changes line 7100 replacing

```
if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && !process.browser) {
  return response.buffer();
}
```

by

```
if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && !process.browser) {
  return response.blob();
}
```

And commenting line 7109

```
if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && !process.browser) {
    //blob.type = contentType;
}
```

It's probably a dirty workaround but I'd like to understand why this happens and how to fix it properly.

Thanks

Comment: Why the process.browser is undefined ?

Comment: Finally I've found the root cause of this. To make pouchdb-find work I had to add this in my polyfills.ts file: (window as any).global = window; but I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50645663/10978653 and I added (window as any).global = window;(window as any).process = {};(window as any).process.nextTick = setTimeout; and this explains why process was undefined

Comment: Excellent investigation.  Well done.  I think you should update you answer to make it easy for future victims of that problem to learn quickly what to do about it.  [ Nice to know it's an Angular problem ... I use VueJs  ;-)   ]